# Print bean object in java

Tags: java, javabeans

I tried to print a bean object as following.

```
CNSLResponseInfo csnlObject = new CNSLResponseInfo();
System.out.println(csnlObject .toString());
```

It gives output as below.

```
org.omo.model.CNSLResponseInfo@59d7305f
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks You

Comment: You will need to override `toString()` of your class to explicitly specify what has to be printed. The default implementation of `toString()` returns / prints  `ClassName@HexValueOfHashCodeOfInstance`

Comment: You need to `@Override` default feature of `toString()` to print data in your format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't ovveride `toString()`, it calls the default implementation you need to ovveride `toString()` and provide your own implementation.

Right now it's printing the default implementation of Object class `toString()` method, which is implemted in way to give the the `unsigned hexadecimal` representation of the hash code of the object.

To start with read [What is the best standard style for a toString implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946529/what-is-the-best-standard-style-for-a-tostring-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `toString` method in your `CNSLResponseInfo` class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override toString() in CNSLResponseInfo class. Without it, the object class toString() is called, which is implemented to return FullyQualifiedClassName@Hashcode

Comment: There is no guarantee that the second part will be *address* of the object

Comment: @TheLostMind Can say `dynamic address` though ;)

Comment: @TheLostMind, sorry my bad, I meant the object's hashcode. Edited my comment

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - Not necessarily. Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()). *As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)* :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Agreed. Exactly my point too :) The internal address keep changes over time.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - Yes, but the hashCode remains the same :P

Answer (score 0):

Override the `.toString()` method of the class `CNSLResponseInfo` and then call `System.out.println(csnlObject);`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return prop1 + ", " + prop2 + ", " + prop3;
}
```

Comment: I see no reason for downvoting this answer

Comment: Downvoter should atleast mention the reason.

Comment: Seems someone just got 125 reputation and testing. Downvote without reason is nothing than a -2.