# Printing contents from an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

so I'm trying to figure out how to print the actual contents, not memory locations, of my array list

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class hw2redo 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
         //Scan file for data
         GeometricObject g = null;
         BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
            Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(file);
            //Create dynamic array list
            ArrayList<GeometricObject> list = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();
            //Scan data and add data to list
            while(diskScanner.hasNext())
            {
                String geolist = diskScanner.nextLine();
                g = recreateObject(geolist);

                list.add(g);

            }

            showObjects(list);

    }
    private static GeometricObject recreateObject(String data)
    {
        GeometricObject object = new GeometricObject(data);
        return object;
    }
    private static void showObjects(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list)
    {
    for(GeometricObject o : list)
      System.out.println(o);
    }


}
class GeometricObject
{

    public GeometricObject(String data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

So here is my code. I have tried using the toString() and Arrays.toString() but they dont seem applicable for an arraylist (I tried because they worked on my regular arrays).

The output I'm recieving is

```
// Output
GeometricObject@55f96302
GeometricObject@3d4eac69
GeometricObject@42a57993
GeometricObject@75b84c92
GeometricObject@6bc7c054
GeometricObject@232204a1
```

which is good because I'm close, I just need to figure out how to print the actual contents.

The content I'm looking for in my file.txt is

```
Circle,green,false,4.0
Circle,blue,false,2.0
Circle,blue,true,7.0
Rectangle,orange,true,10.0,6.0
Rectangle,green,false,5.0,11.0
Rectangle,red,true,14.0,12.0
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to override `GeometricObject#toString()`

Comment: Could you elaborate a little further? I know override means to provide the exact same argument list of the method, but what would i provide inside the method?  @Eran

Comment: @RiFFRAFF You need not to change the current method. Keep the code as it is and just ovveride the toString method in GeometricObject. That's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `toString` method in your class:

```
class GeometricObject
{

    private String data;

    public GeometricObject(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

Without the Override, you are using `Object.toString()`. Object's `toString` prints out the class name and the hashcode of the object, as you have observed.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you! To be honest though, I'm not 100% sure why adding that code gave me the correct output. Is there anyway you could explain at all.

Comment: @RiFFRAFF I recommend heading over to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_tostring.htm and have a bit more of a play

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println(o);
```

When you call System.out.println, That apparently calls the toString() method of your Object. Since you didn't ovveride `toString()`, it calls the default implementation. Ovveride toString() method to print as you wish.

```
public class GeometricObject {

....


 @Override
    public String toString() {
       // return  string representation of your object.
    }


}
```

To starts with  :[What is the best standard style for a toString implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946529/what-is-the-best-standard-style-for-a-tostring-implementation)